# How can I find an identifiable network name over ethernet?

Tags: ethernet, host-name-resolution

As a network client over wifi, I can get a BSSID that shows a recognizable network name. Are there any equivalent method over an ethernet connection under nixes ?

My question concerns personal computers on a DHCP lease, that could be connected to either a home's or a shop's shared Access Point. I'm looking for solutions implemented as libraries if possible.

I suppose the gateway MAC address would be (almost) unique, and would let me identify the network I'm connected to. But it's not recognizable - because a bunch of hexadecimal blocks is not easy to remember I guess.

I read in another related SE question's comments that I could traceroute some known place to try and find out the gateway's hostname. But I suppose this would not work when connected to an offline LAN.

Comment: why would a wired network require a name? ... there is no multiple choice of LANs when a computer is plugged into a hardwired connection

Comment: Can you explain why you would need to identify a network by name?

Comment: I'm exploring the idea of a firewall that adapts its policy to the network the machine it runs on is connected to. Having an Access Point readable name is quite needed.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for [Link Layer Discovery Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_Layer_Discovery_Protocol), using the command `lldpd` and associated [suite of tools](https://lldpd.github.io/).  It probably won’t be as useful on consumer hardware, but this is as close as I can think of a protocol that lets a device query the network device for a name.

I suppose for consumer devices you could just hit port 80 or 443 on the gateway and see if it has anything.

Comment: Looks like a pretty good hint, even though LLDP is mute on my home network. Parsing whatever comes out of port 80 on the gateway seems doable but hard to get robust.Is there anything close to a hostname on DHCP servers' advertisement ?